# Visual studio's memory window only contains question marks

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, dump

I'm working on the crash dump of a standard C++ program.

I'm having a problem with following piece of code:

```cpp
_variant_t* pvarTemp;
pvarTemp = <static_cast><_variant_t*> (pointer_array->GetAt(i));
if (!pvarTemp) continue;
pvarTemp->Clear();
```

As I presume something's going wrong in memory, I decided to have a look at the memory window (menu "Debug", "Windows", "Memory", "Memory 1"), where I entered the memory address of `pvarTemp`, but I only saw some question marks.

The crash dump itself is just a small crashdump, hereby `PYKD`'s `targetSystem().desc` result (in Windgb):

```py
0:049> !py
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> print targetSystem().desc
User mini dump: C:\Temp_Folder\CRASH.DMP
```

My question is: what's the reason of the question marks?

1. The reason for having the question marks also is the reason for the application to crash.
2. As I'm working with a small crashdump, the memory addresses, mentioned in the dump, might not be trustworthy, so the question marks are normal behaviour.

Which one of the two is correct?

Comment: What question marks? I see none.

Comment: I mean, in the "Memory" debug window, I only see question marks where I expect some information.

Comment: If I remember right, dump window shows question marks if it is requested to dump contents of non-accessable addresses. (I mean addresses which are not part of associated memory range of process i.e. would cause access violation.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing postmortem debugging.  Generally, crash dumps don't capture all the memory in use by the process.  If you try to inspect memory that wasn't included in the dump, you'll see question marks.

If you're doing live debugging, question marks mean the address isn't mapped into the process space.

Comment: So, a general approach is not to use crash dumps, but to generate full memory dumps, even in case of a crash.

Comment: Most of the time, including all mapped memory in the crash dump is overkill.  A minidump will generally have all of the thread stacks, a bunch of process context, and sometimes even active parts of the heap.  If your crash dump has a pointer to memory that wasn't captured, there's a good chance it was a bad pointer that was pointing to unmapped memory.  If the crash reason was a memory access violation at address 0xDEADBEEF and the memory window shows question marks at 0xDEADBEEF, then it's almost certain that a full memory dump wouldn't include that address either.